# Restoring MySQL database data from ibdata1 and ib_logfile

Tags: mysql, centos

I am trying to restore a MySQL database. I have the following:

`ibdata1`

`ib_logfile0`

`ib_logfile1`

`.frm` files restored as I have a backup of the structure.

Is it possible to restore the data for the database having the above? The server runs on CentOS.

Comment: Theoretically yes you can. Did you backup the full data dir (default in centos /var/lib/mysql)? If so you should be fine. Just stop your server, replace your data dir with those files and start the server again.

Comment: Unfortunately `.ibd` files have been deleted. Am I correct to assume that without those the data cannot be restored?

Comment: Was innodb_file_per_table  enabled? If so, yes you lost your data, if not, maybe (maybe) you can recover from frm files and ibdata1